# Updating label text makes whole scene disappear

Tags: xcode, scenekit

When I update the text that is in a label on one of my scenes, that scene disappears or becomes transparent. It is difficult to troubleshoot since there is no error. What could possibly cause this? the only code that mentions the labels I have been updating is below:

```
var root: SKNode? { return self.childNode(withName: "root") }
var storyWindow: SKSpriteNode? { return self.root?.childNode(withName: "storyWindow") as? SKSpriteNode }
var titleWindow: SKSpriteNode? { return self.root?.childNode(withName: "titleWindow") as? SKSpriteNode }
var subtitleWindow: SKSpriteNode? { return self.root?.childNode(withName: "subtitleWindow") as? SKSpriteNode }
var content: SKSpriteNode? { return self.root?.childNode(withName: "content") as? SKSpriteNode }
```

Comment: A bug in your code almost certainly. It is even more difficult (or impossible) for us to help you than you helping yourself since you do not show any code or interface.

Comment: Perry, just so you understand: your question is being downvoted because it lacks context. If you edit your question and provide details and code, people will happily help you.

Comment: I added the only thing I thought would be relevant, I was assuming this was a simple problem from my lack of experience. and not an actual bug since this is a finished project that I am taking over and have no guidance to how it was built. Also I don't know swift or Xcode so Im reverse engineering a language I don't understand.